# How do I stop running total from resetting to 0 in void function?

Tags: c++, function, void, cumulative-sum

I have an assignment where I'm supposed to make a restaurant menu. The menu must loop until the user enters 4 to get the bill. I'm supposed to use a function to display the menu, and another function to calculate the running total AND display the bill when the user finishes ordering.

Problem is, I have to initialize `runningTotal` before I use it, and I don't know where to put it to stop it resetting to its initialization. Originally I had my calculating function, `cost()`, set up like this:

```
void cost(const double ITEM_PRICE, int amtOfItemOrdered, bool isDoneOrdering) {

// initializing runningTotal and declaring other variables...
    double runningTotal = 0, tip, finalBill;

// if statement so bill only displays when order is finished...
    if (isDoneOrdering == false)

        // calculate running total...
        runningTotal += (ITEM_PRICE * amtOfItemOrdered);

    else {

        // when order finishes, calculate and display bill...
        tip = (runningTotal * 0.20);
        finalBill = (runningTotal + tip);

        cout << "\nFood total: " << runningTotal <<
                "\nTip: " << tip <<
                "\nFinal Bill: " << finalBill;
    }
```

Which I think results in `runningTotal` resetting to 0 every time the function executes. When I run the program, order something, and press 4 to see the bill, everything in the bill comes up as 0. Here's an example of the output:

```
Food total: 0
Tip: 0
Final Bill: 0
```

I thought it might help to move `runningTotal` outside the `cost()` function like this:

```
int main() {

// initializing runningTotal with 0 in main...
        double runningTotal = 0;

// other variables...
    const double ITEM1_PRICE = 2.50, ITEM2_PRICE = 3.50, ITEM3_PRICE = 4.50;
    int itemOrdered, amtOfItemOrdered;
    bool isDoneOrdering = false;

// loop menu choice until order is finished...
    do {
        displayMenu(ITEM1_PRICE, ITEM2_PRICE, ITEM3_PRICE);
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> itemOrdered;

        // don't ask "how many" when done ordering...
        if (itemOrdered != 4) {
            cout << "\nHow many? ";
            cin >> amtOfItemOrdered;
        }

        switch (itemOrdered) {
        case 1:

        // passing runningTotal to cost() so cost() can use it...
            cost(ITEM1_PRICE, amtOfItemOrdered, isDoneOrdering, runningTotal);
            break;

        case 2:
            cost(ITEM2_PRICE, amtOfItemOrdered, isDoneOrdering, runningTotal);
            break;
        case 3:
            cost(ITEM3_PRICE, amtOfItemOrdered, isDoneOrdering, runningTotal);
            break;
        case 4:
            isDoneOrdering = true;
            cost(0, 0, isDoneOrdering, runningTotal);

            // zeroes are here because cost() asks for parameters,
            // but we're done adding to running total...

            break;
        default:
            0; // empty placeholder statement...
        }
    } while (isDoneOrdering == false);
}
```

But this has the same result. I think what's happening here is that `runningTotal` in `main` is different from `runningTotal` in `cost()`, and the value 0 in `main`'s `runningTotal` is getting passed to the `runningTotal` in `cost()`, which is resetting it anyway?

I thought about making a return statement for `runningTotal`, `tip`, and `finalBill`, and displaying the bill outside of the function, but I think the assignment wants me to stick to void functions.

Just tested initializing `runningTotal` to 1 in `main`, and the bill displays the following:

```
Food total: 1
Tip: 0.2
Final Bill: 1.2
```

So I do think initialization is the problem here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Introduce `double intermediateTotal` parameter in the function and make it to return `double`, new intermediate total. Pass `runningTotal` in the main to that function and assign the returned value to `runningTotal`.

Comment: Options include (1) pass `runningTotal` as an argument by reference (or pointer) and update it in the function [this requires the caller to correctly handle creating and initialising the passed variable to zero].   (2)  make `runningTotal` a variable at file scope, with static storage duration, and provide another function to reset it before calling `cost()` multiple times [like any usage of static variables, this imposes some restrictions].

Comment: Since you've changed the signature of `cost` in the second example, you should post the updated signature. We're curious as to whether you're passing the additional parameter as `double` by value or `double &` by reference. It needs to be by reference.

Comment: *"my calculating function"* -- Functions should have one purpose only. You have two calculations -- calculating the cost of each selection (accounting for the quantity) and calculating the final total (including tip). Two calculations suggest you should have two functions.

Comment: *"I think the assignment wants me to stick to void functions"* -- that's a sad assignment. *(Relevance of this comment to Stack Overflow: One of the criteria for up/down votes is "useful", and a question bound by unreasonable restrictions is not particularly useful.)*

Comment: To directly answer your question: If you use `static double runningTotal=0;` it will not get reset every time you enter the function. However as others have commented, this is not proper design and you should use one of the approaches mentioned in other comments and answers instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is C++, it makes sense to use classes.

Consider a class to encapsulate the cost calculation, and a separate class for storing the menu.

```
constexpr double TIP_MARGIN = 0.2;

class BillCalculator
{
    double m_RunningTotal = 0.0;
public:
    void AddCost(const double price, int count)
    {
        m_RunningTotal += price * count;
    }
   
    double CalculateTip() const
    {
        return m_RunningTotal * TIP_MARGIN;
    }

    double CalculateTotalBill() const
    {
        return GetRunningTotal() + CalculateTip();
    }

    double GetRunningTotal() const
    {
        return m_RunningTotal;
    }
};
```

Instantiate both classes in `main`. Having one function that focuses on I/O only will make the code easier to follow.

If you need to pass an instance of either of the classes that you created, pass it **by reference**.

Answer (score -2):

Variables defined and initialized in the **scope of function** will stay in the function.
In your code, runningTotal in the **main()** function and runningTotal in the **cost()** function and thus have different memory space in the memory (although they have same names).

I've noticed you want to access the value of the variable runningTotal in the **cost()** function and also to modify the variable. Like Peter's commented, you can do that by 2 ways:

1. Passing runningTotal into the function cost() by **parameter** or **pointer**, that is you give the function the variable by identifying the memory space of that variable.

For example:

By parameter:

```
void cost(your variables..., double& runningTotal) //by parameter.

//calling the function:
cost(your variables..., runningTotal); //it's the same as calling normal function

//using the variable
//you can use its the same as normal.
//note that, any changes made in this function will affect the variable outside, so be carefull
```

By pointer:

```
void cost(your varialbe..., double* runningTotal) //by pointer.

//calling the funtion
cost(your variables...,&runningTotal);

//using the variable
//As pointer is simply the address of the variable itself
//you'll have to dereference it before using by adding a * before the variable
*runningTotal = *runningTotal +1;
//note that, changes here also affect the variable outside.
```

2. By using a variable of a file scope (global scope):

   ```
   //the variable

   double runningTotal;

   void cost(your variable....){//your code}

   int main(){ //your code}
   ```

Note that, change in this way still affect the variable outside

Comment: Reference semantics have a way to backfire in larger project.  And with NVRO you can just use `double cost(your variables)` where the return valus is the running_total without incurring overhead so it might help to rename the function `calculate_running_total` (which makes the code more self describing too). And just remove the variant with pointers, the use of raw pointers in C++ is not recommended and it will require you to start testing the pointer for validity (it not being nullptr).

Comment: The last option with a global variable is just a very bad move. Global variables should be avoided at all costs. It too creates an "implicit" interface between different pieces of code  that is not self documenting. Imagine another function starting to "misuse" that globel. Easy to avoid in a small bit of code, impossible to police in a large code base.